# How to detect a cell containing a string and next 2 cells after that in r dataframe?

Tags: r

I'm wondering how can I detect some string from R data frame and next 2 ( or n ) cells after that cell from same row. And after detecting it would be my goal to produce a indicator variable from those 3 cells.

It's a lot easier to show what I mean by producing an example. So lets say my data frame looks like this

```
table <-  data.frame( x1 = c(1,4,6,"Y"), x2 = c("Y",1,"Y",5), x3 = c(1,2,5,4),
                     x4 = c(2,NA,4,"Y"), x5 = c(NA,NA,6,1), x6 = c(NA,NA,1,5))
x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6
1  Y  1  2 NA NA
4  1  2  NA NA NA
6  Y  5  4  6  1
Y  5  4  Y  1  5
```

And the goal would be table that looks something like this

```
goal_table <- data.frame(Y12 = c(1,0,0,0),Y54 = c(0,0,1,1), Y15 = c(0,0,0,1))

Y12 Y54 Y15
1   0   0
0   0   0
0   1   0
0   1   1
```

So because at the original table, the first row contains cell "Y" followed by "1" and "2", the goal table would then have column "Y12" with indicator 1 and apply that same logic to all other two number combinations that are after "Y".

Some information that may make this task easier:
Y is always followed by at least two numbers.
If a row contains NA in lets say x2, every following x3,x4,x5,... will also be NA (as seen in example).
The goal table doesn't have to be its own table, the columns can just be added to the original table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
table %>% 
   mutate_all(as.character) %>% 
   mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = -rn, values_drop_na = TRUE) %>% 
   group_by(rn) %>% 
   group_by(grp = cumsum(value == 'Y'), add = TRUE) %>%
   summarise(value = str_c(head(value, 3), collapse="")) %>% 
   filter(str_detect(value, '^Y')) %>% 
   ungroup %>%
   select(-grp) %>%
   mutate(new = 1) %>%
   group_by(rn) %>%
   mutate(rn2 = row_number()) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = new, 
           values_fill = list(new = 0)) %>%
   select(-rn, - rn2)
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#    Y12   Y54   Y15
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     0     0
#2     0     1     0
#3     0     1     0
#4     0     0     1
```